# Проблема с выводом произвольных полей через foreach на WP

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

Ребята, я не программист, но возникла проблема.

Есть код который тянет с доп. страниц параметры с произвольных страниц.

```html
<?php foreach ($metas as $meta_key => $meta_val):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='35%'><?= $meta_key; ?></td>
                        <td width='65%'><?= $meta_val[0]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Поставил недавно плагин All in One Seo Pack и закрыл доп. страницы от робота, как не нужные. Но этот код начал тянуть доп. параметры от All in One Seo Pack
на страницу
_aioseop_custom_link    http://***
_aioseop_noindex    on
_aioseop_sitemap_exclude    on
_aioseop_disable    on

Попытался их исключить через if, но видимо где-то допусти ошибку:

```html
<?php foreach ($metas as $meta_key => $meta_val) {
if($meta_key == $found_tag['_aioseop_custom_link']) {
unset($metas[$meta_key]);
    }  
elseif($meta_key == $found_tag['_aioseop_noindex']) {
unset($metas[$meta_key]);
    }  
elseif($meta_key == $found_tag['aioseop_sitemap_exclude']) {
unset($metas[$meta_key]);
    }   
elseif($meta_key == $found_tag['_aioseop_disable']) {        
unset($metas[$meta_key]);
    }  
    }; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='35%'><?= $meta_key; ?></td>
                        <td width='65%'><?= $meta_val[0]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем косяк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проще всего это сделать как-то так:

```
<?php foreach ($metas as $meta_key => $meta_val) :
    if(stripos($meta_key, 'aioseop') === false) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td width='35%'><?= $meta_key; ?></td>
            <td width='65%'><?= $meta_val[0]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Заработало

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас php 5.6 и больше, можно отфильтровать так перед циклом

```
$metas = array_filter($metas, function($k) {
  return strpos($k,'aio') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: так?
'<?php $metas = array_filter($metas, function($k) {
  return strpos($k,'aio') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
foreach ($metas as $meta_key => $meta_val):?>'
Если да, то таблица просто сносится

Comment: ну, значит меньше чем 5.6

Comment: А что такое $found_tag? Наверное, правильнее `$meta_key == '_aioseop_disable'`

Comment: Нет, так тоже не работает
Брал отсюда
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949259/how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Ниже возьмите код. Только там должно быть `stripos($meta_key, 'aioseop') !== false`

Comment: неее, вот теперь у него та правильно.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо за помощь